# ASP.NET MVC Web Deploy using Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

so I'm using IIS web deploy inside .NET MVC  and I have my publishing profile (pubxml) like following:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Target Name="TakeOffline" AfterTargets="BeforePublish" >
        <Message Text="Taking application offline" Importance="high" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="_app_offline.htm" DestinationFiles="$(publishUrl)\app_offline.htm" />
    </Target>

    <!-- BEGIN: Add this -->
    <Target Name="RestoreOnline" AfterTargets="AfterPublish" >
        <Message Text="Restoring application online" Importance="high" />
        <Delete Files="$(publishUrl)\app_offline.htm" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The tutorial where I found this method is as following:

https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/11/08/automatically-make-your-asp-net-web-application-offline-while-deploying-using-web-deploy-in-visual-studio-2017/

What I'm trying to achieve here is:

- During deployment - bring website automatically down using app_offline.htm element [copying from my project's root folder called _app_offline.htm and upon copying it to server => rename it app_offline.htm
- After the deployment is done - delete the app_offline.htm file on remote server

After I did everything - this is not working - when I do the publishing through VS studio 2019 - it simply just copies the file _app_offline.htm into my remote server's website root directory and that's pretty much it...

What am I doing wrong here and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Comment: Does your project work properly locally? Can you share the content of app_offline.htm?

Comment: @samwu yes it works, when I rename file to app_offline site gets off..

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.